# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' when installing chromadb via pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, chromadb

I'm trying to install chromadb via pip on Ubuntu. When I run the command

`pip install chromadb`

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/tbreimer/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/tbreimer/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/tbreimer/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 380, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 116, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 104, in run
          bdist_wheel = self.get_finalized_command('bdist_wheel')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 304, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 860, in get_command_obj
          klass = self.get_command_class(command)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 979, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 28, in <module>
          from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1fpsm_d5/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I've installed `libffi-dev` and ensured that `libffi.so` is loaded by using the command `ldconfig` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul) post

I've also reinstalled python using the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3`

I've also tried completely uninstalling python and it's dependencies which doesn't seem to accomplish anything besides breaking the windowing system so that my laptop boots to the terminal, forcing me to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

What am I doing wrong?