# lsb_release not working after install Python 3.6.3 from source

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

platform: ubuntu 17.04 server

The ubuntu 17.04 server installation includes python 2.7 and python 3.5.
I installed the Python 3.6.3 manually from source. However, the `lsb_release -a` failed:

```
root@birds:~# lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

But if I modify the first line of the file lsb_release from
`#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es`
to
`#!/usr/bin/python3.5 -Es`
it works again.

```
root@birds:~# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Here are the module search path:

python3.5

```
root@birds:~# python3.5
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:58:41) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys

>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

>>> import lsb_release

>>> exit()
```

python3

```
root@birds:~# python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 14 2017, 20:35:42) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys

>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'

>>> exit()
```

does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Why didnt you install Python 3.6 from a PPA?

Comment: Looks like you used `make install` instead of `make altinstall`? (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/unix.html#building-python).  You *might* be able to recover by pointing the `python3` symlink at your 3.5 binary, but you might need to reinstall the entire OS.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965043/no-module-named-lsb-release-after-install-python-3-6-3-from-source

Answer (score 18):

**Solution:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

**Explain:**

We can see in `/usr/bin/lsb_release`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es

# lsb_release command for Debian
# (C) 2005-10 Chris Lawrence <lawrencc@debian.org>
#    This package is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation; version 2 dated June, 1991.
#    This package is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this package; if not, write to the Free Software
#    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
#    02110-1301 USA
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
import os
import re

import lsb_release
```

The key step is `import lsb_release`, but the problem is `Python 3.6` doesn't have this module.

So, **you must have overrided `python3` from `python3.5` to `python3.6`. That's why your `lsb_release` is broken.**

To verify it, we can see in `python3.6`:

```
➜  ~ python3.6 
Python 3.6.4 (default, Feb  6 2018, 16:57:12) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

then in `python3.5`:

```
➜  ~ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
>>> lsb_release.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py'
```

where is this file:

```
➜  ~ ll /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jul   7  2016 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py -> ../../../share/pyshared/lsb_release.py
```

So, this module `lsb_release` exist in `python3.5` but not exist in `python3.6`. And We find it eventually!

Now let's fix it through add a link to the original `lsb_release.py` file!

It works for me!

Comment: On my machine (mint) the lsb_release runs python with the -Es flags so site-packages are not on the path.  Adding the symbolic link to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lsb_release.py works instead

Comment: it works for me at Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64,   sys.path and ln -s... gave me the path to the solution

Answer (score 4):

This happens when `dist-packages` is wiped out or not accessible to the python installation.

I got into this when I removed a `dist-packages/` in `/usr/lib/python3` - because there were some user-installed packages conflicting with my local packages.

To fix, you can try:

`sudo apt reinstall lsb-release`

This fixed it for me.  It also avoids the issue with the sibling answer of purging `lsb-release`. No need.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with python 3.6 and python 3.7 on Raspberry Pi, but I thing it shall work anywhere.

The only thing that works like a charm was to move the lsb_release to a backup file.

```
 sudo mv /usr/bin/lsb_release /usr/bin/lsb_release_back
```

The complete doc can be found here: [readthedocs.io].[1]https://neoctobers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rpi/install_python3.html

Answer (score -2):

You just purge existing lsb-release and reinstall it again. It will solve your problem.

```
$ sudo apt purge lsb-release
$ sudo apt install lsb-release
```

Comment: DONT do this. I have and it removed all sorts of stuff that should not have been removed.

Comment: if you don't care about settings and configuration, it's a valid solution. Worked for me.