# i am not able to work on pip command and uninstall it.

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, uninstallation

while trying to uninstall pip or working with command pip this error is showing up. Can anyone help me how to make pip command work or to uninstall it and re-install again. Can you post those command that i need to try. Thank you.

```
 nuk@nuk-desktop:/$ pip uninstall pip
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 46, in run
        with self._build_session(options) as session:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 81, in _build_session
        insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 338, in __init__
        self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 101, in user_agent
        zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 120, in linux_distribution
        return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 634, in linux_distribution
        self.version(),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 688, in version
        self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 836, in lsb_release_attr
        return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 522, in __get__
        ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 933, in _lsb_release_info
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 246, in main
        return command.main(cmd_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 264, in main
        timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 81, in _build_session
        insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 338, in __init__
        self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 101, in user_agent
        zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 120, in linux_distribution
        return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 634, in linux_distribution
        self.version(),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 688, in version
        self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 836, in lsb_release_attr
        return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 522, in __get__
        ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 933, in _lsb_release_info
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip is showing error 'lsb\_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967202/pip-is-showing-error-lsb-release-a-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D++Command+lsb_release+returned+non-zero+exit+status

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466255/8645590.