# Any conda command shows this error report

Tags: python

```
$ conda info --envs

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 317, in execute
        info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 135, in get_info_dict
        _supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 164, in _supplement_index_with_system
        dist_name, dist_version = context.os_distribution_name_version
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 863, in os_distribution_name_version
        from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
        _distro = LinuxDistribution()
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
        self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
      File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

`$ /home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda info --envs`


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:  y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 317, in execute
    info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 135, in get_info_dict
    _supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 164, in _supplement_index_with_system
    dist_name, dist_version = context.os_distribution_name_version
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
    cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 863, in os_distribution_name_version
    from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
    self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 155, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1374, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1085, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1129, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1144, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self._execute_upload(error_report)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1306, in _execute_upload
    'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1104, in user_agent
    return context.user_agent
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
    cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 805, in user_agent
    builder.append("%s/%s" % self.os_distribution_name_version)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
    cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 863, in os_distribution_name_version
    from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
    self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Hi, I keep getting this ERROR REPORT for any conda command (conda info, conda install, conda whatever).

I removed and re-installed anaconda but then I get the same error, so I removed everything and installed miniconda, then I re-installed miniconda, then I also re-installed Ubuntu.

None of the above clearly solved the problem and this ERROR REPORT comes and goes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Haven't seen that in a while... does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967202/pip-is-showing-error-lsb-release-a-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1) fix your problem?

Comment: What operating system and what computer are you running this on?  What happens if you type `lsb_release -a` at a command line?  All Debian-derived systems (including Ubuntu) have that command, unless you have changed the path.

Comment: @TimRoberts `lsb_release -a` returns :: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 38, in get_distro_info
    csvfile = open('/usr/share/distro-info/%s.csv' % origin.lower())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv'

Comment: What Ubuntu release did you install, exactly?  Is this a bare metal install, or are you running a VM or in WSL?   Your Ubuntu is damaged, and you haven't given us anything to go on.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh, it's WSL-Ubuntu-18.04, downloaded from Microsoft store, Win10.

Comment: Do `sudo apt install lsb-release`.  Not sure why it wouldn't be installed.

Comment: @TimRoberts Done, but the problem has not been solved yet :( still getting the same err.

Comment: If you installed it, then that error can't happen.  Does `lsb_release -a` work from a command line?

Comment: @TimRoberts NO, it is returning the same error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 39, in get_distro_info
    csvfile = open('/usr/share/distro-info/%s.csv' % origin.lower())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv'
`