# Does TensorFlow 1.9 support Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm hesitating whether to downgrade to Python 3.6 or install a new version of TensorFlow.

Does TensorFlow 1.9 support Python 3.7?

Comment: you can run python 3.7 with Tensorflow 1.12 from here https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.12.0

Comment: What do you mean by run it from there? shall I download the file and where to save it?

Comment: I have built the .whl for tensorflow 1.12.0 with python 3.7.2
pip3 install tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
ensure pip3 is pointing to 3.7.2
file is here https://sourceforge.net/projects/getprathamos/files/Adyah/BD_ML/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
right now only cpu build is available

Answer (score 15):

I was able to install Tensorflow 1.12.0 with Python 3.7 on MacOS, with the following command.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 12):

Not yet. It seems there are some variables named "async", which has become a keyword in 3.7. Shouldn't be too difficult to fix, but still a problem.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20444

Answer (score 5):

Probably not yet.

First of all, you will probably get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because some parameters and variables at the `pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py` module have the name `async` which is a reserved keyword in Python 3.7.0 (see also this [post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690)).

However, you can solve this by simply changing the name of all these (`Ctrl + R` and `Replace All`) from `async` to for example `async1`.

The problem is that then you will probably get a `ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'` which perhaps may be fixed for any previous version before Python 3.7.0 as this [post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690) on StackOverflow suggests but personally I could not fix it on my laptop with Python 3.7.0 .

Consequently, I simply downgraded to Python 3.6.6 and now Tensorflow is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whl built here. However in my run it was cpu version.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 2):

as of Aug 26tH, there is an update on the tensorflow github site
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/21202

Answer (score 2):

[Tensorflow 1.13.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.1) now supports Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally Worked for me!**

On Python 3.6.4 (even 3.6.5 failed for me)
Install Python3.6.4 from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

If you're facing issues with Python pkgs that you already had on you older version just revert it using this post:
[python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx/51367161#51367161)

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments on github 
see 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-457185528

by member av8ramit 
"We are aiming to try and have Windows and Ubuntu python binaries by rc2 or the official."
the estimated release date for 2019-02-03

however on 
https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/687
one can read from a winpython contributor:
"Tensorflow-2 is 2019, Tensorflow-1 on Python-3.7 is still not in sight"

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work after searching for a while.

As Tensorflow only supports Python 3.6 as of now, you can install a different version of python alongside your standard one. Here are the steps I followed:

- Download the Python3.6 tgz file from the official website (eg. Python-3.6.6.tgz)
- Unpack it with `tar -xvzf Python-3.6.6.tgz`
- `cd Python-3.6.6`
- run `./configure`
- run `make altinstall` to install it (`install` vs `altinstall` explanation here [Difference in details between "make install" and "make altinstall"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall))

You'll normally find your new python install under `/usr/local/bin`. Now you can create a new virtualenv specifying the python version with:

- `virtualenv --python=python3.6 env3.6`
- Get into the virtualenv running the command `source env3.6/source/bin/activate`.
- Install tensorflow with the classic `pip install tensorflow`
- Profit

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
*conda create -n yourenvname python=3.6    
*conda activate yourenvname 
*pip install tensorflow
```

then it will work like rock.