# tensorflow import issue for python 3.7

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7

After installing tensorflow for python 3.7, I tried to import it but it gave me a syntax error.
the command used for installation :
 sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl

I don't think tensorflow has supported python3.7 yet. Is there a way to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f5Pe.png)

Comment: I believe some keywords are added to python3.7 which cause conflict with existing tensorflow code so currently there is no support for python3.7

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by simply changing the name of all these (`Ctrl + R` and `Replace All`) from `async` to for example `async1` as also this [post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690) suggests.

But even after fixing it you will probably encounter other problems with Tensorflow and Python 3.7.0 . For more details see my answer here: [Does TensorFlow 1.9 support Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235428/does-tensorflow-1-9-support-python-3-7/52057512#52057512)

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow import for python 3.7
for Anaconda 2019.03 with Python 3.7 version

for CPU

create command:

conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow

activate command:

conda activate tensorflow_env

Import command:

(tensorflow_env) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > print(tf.**version**)

for GPU

create command:

conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu

activate command:

conda activate tensorflow_gpuenv

Import command:

(tensorflow_gpuenv) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > print(tf.**version**)