# How to Fix Keras and Tensorflow Import Error In Python for Neural Network Project

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Recently, in order to complete an experiment, I have attempted running a program in the IDLE integrated developer environment for Python; this program imports various modules (librosa, glob, numpy, matplotlib and Keras (running on Tensorflow). I developed the program with these modules being imported alone, in order to test for preliminary errors. When I ran only the code for importing these libraries, Python produced this error message in the shell:

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/surengrigorian/Documents/Stage1.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File                "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-        packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.display
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

The expected results would be, simply put, no errors. I have attempted to investigate the error message and most of these errors relate to the backend programs that it is running. For more information, visit this site:
https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/identifying-the-genre-of-a-song-with-neural-networks-851db89c42f0

I would also like to know if you have any suggestions as to how to develop a neural network able to classify classical music by genre or if you know any neural network design interfaces that use a graphical user interface. Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide. I hope you have a Happy New Year.

Comment: Pyhton 3.7 & tensorflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235428/does-tensorflow-1-9-support-python-3-7

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.