# How to chose which 3.x python version on cmd?

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code working with python 3.6.6 but I have 3.7.2 in enviroment too.When I try to run my code in cmd, it's trying to run with 3.7.2.How can I chance it?

Comment: Please tell us which OS you're using. Windows, or MAcs

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and also my problem solved.Thanks.

Comment: Ok then I geuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can tell a script to run with a specific version of Python, commonly you'd use a shebang:

```
#!/user/bin/env/python3.x
```

However, I think this only works for Linux/Mac which it sounds like you aren't on if you're referring to cmd. You may want to check out this answer which has a few other options that may help: [How do I tell a Python script to use a particular version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-do-i-tell-a-python-script-to-use-a-particular-version)

Alternatively you can set up a virtual environment, which allows you to run different versions of Python, modules and any other environment settings for a specific project. If that sounds like a better solution then this answer should help you out: [(Easiest) Way to use Python 3.6 and 3.7 on same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138280/easiest-way-to-use-python-3-6-and-3-7-on-same-computer)

Comment: I used virtual environment way.Thanks for help.