# How to install python scipts to /usr/local/bin on macos?

Tags: python, macos, pip, bin

There is a package, called [pysyte](https://github.com/jalanb/pysyte), which provides [a few scripts](https://github.com/jalanb/pysyte/bin) for use in the shell.

On any unixy OS I'd do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jalanb/pysyte
$ cd pysyte
$ pip install -r ./requirements.txt
$ pip install -e .
```

And I would expect the [package's bin/](https://github.com/jalanb/pysyte/bin) scripts to be installed to the same `bin/` that `pip` is in. That works everywhere for me if `pip` is in a virtualenv.

But it doesn't work on `macOs` where Python is installed by `Homebrew`.

When `pip` is `/usr/local/bin/pip` the package scripts do not get installed to `/usr/local/bin`, but to most recent of the Python versions at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/*/bin/`.

These are not directories that I want to add to my `$PATH`, so I'd prefer to have the packages' scripts installed to, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/kat`

Am I missing a config setting in Homebrew to get the scripts "linked on"? Or to ask Homebrew to **not** do a framewwork install?

Or should I bypass Homebrew, and [altinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16018463/500942) a fresh Python from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) to `/usr/local` - as I would've done on other unixy OSes?

FYI

```
$ ll /usr/local/bin/pip*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 jab admin  4 Jul  7  2018 /usr/local/bin/pip -> pip3*
lrwxrwxr-x 1 jab admin 66 Jun 11  2018 /usr/local/bin/pip3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3*
lrwxrwxr-x 1 jab admin 68 Jun 11  2018 /usr/local/bin/pip3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3.7*
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `python` instead of `pip`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jalanb/pysyte
$ cd pysyte
$ pip install -r ./requirements.txt
$ sudo python setup.py install --install-scripts=/usr/local/bin
```

Which installs the scripts as expected, e.g.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/kat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jalanb jalanb 166 Jul  5 03:32 /usr/local/bin/kat
```