# Python3.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, pip

I have two versions Python-2.7 , Python-3.5  which I was able to access with `python(pip)` and `python3(pip3)` command respectively. Then I have installed an another version of `python (i.e 3.7.5)`.

I have used these commands to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.7.5.tgz
cd Python-3.7.5
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared
make -j6
sudo make altinstall
```

Everything was successful but the only issue is I was not able to access Python-3.7 using the command `python3.7`.

When I used python3.7 it returned this following error:

> python3.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone please help me regarding how to fix this issue?

Info: `OS`: Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)

Output when I type:

```
user_83@debian-241:~$ whereis python     
python: /usr/bin/python3.5m-config 
/usr/bin/python3.5m 
/usr/bin/python2.7-config 
/usr/bin/python3.5 
/usr/bin/python2.7 
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python3.5-config 
/usr/lib/python3.5 
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/etc/python3.5 
/etc/python2.7 
/etc/python 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7
/usr/include/python3.5m 
/usr/include/python3.5 
/usr/include/python2.7 
/usr/share/python 
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

UPDATE:

```
locate libpython3.5m

/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m-pic.a
/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a
/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0

locate libpython3.7m
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.a


sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib 

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libnvinfer.so.5 is not a symbolic link
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libnvonnxparser_runtime.so.0 is not a symbolic link
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libnvonnxparser.so.0 is not a symbolic link
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libnvparsers.so.5 is not a symbolic link
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libnvinfer_plugin.so.5 is not a symbolic link
```

Comment: did you check if apt on Debian doesn't have precompiled Python3.7 ? On Linux Mint I use `apt` to install precompiled Python 3.7 from unofficial repo for Ubuntu - maybe it can works also for Debian - https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: using `find` or `locate` you can try to find `libpython3.7m.so.1.0` and compare its path with full path to `libpython3.5` - maybe you have to manually move it to correct folder.

Comment: I tried to update python using `sudo apt install python2` but it returned python 3.5 as the latest version available. So that's why I installed it via above method.

Comment: @furas can you provide the commands on how to do that. I'm new to linux os. I really have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if `locate` is always installed. It creates database with all filename - `sudo updatedb` - and later you can search - `locate libpython3.7m.so.1.0`. Because it uses database so it search very fast but from time to time you have to use `updatedb` to update data in this database.

Comment: normally should be installed `find`. It search directly in folders - `sudo find / -name libpython3.7` - so it check current content on disk but it may run much slower.

Comment: @furas As you mentioned I tried using `locate libpython3.7m.so.1.0` and it returned `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0`

Comment: and what did you get for `libpython3.5m` ? Is it in the same folder ? If not then try to copy `libpython3.7m.so.1.0` to folder where you have `libpython3.5m`

Comment: @furas can you check the question I updated what I've got for searching `locate libpython3.5m`. It returned multiple locations. Can you tell me what command I should use to copy everything correctly.

Comment: I have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0` and `/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so` similar to folders with `libpython3.5m`. The same with other files: `libpython3.7m.so.1`, `libpython3.7m.so` and `libpython3.7m.a`

Comment: I'm not sure if Debian uses `Python3` to run something in system but maybe you should use `make install` instead of `make altinstall`

Comment: yes even I wasn't sure so I used `make altinstall`. So is there a way to remove everything so I can again install it with `make install`. I don't know the commands to remove.

Comment: For Python `install` runs `altinstall` and few other commands so you don't have to remove it. [Difference in details between “make install” and “make altinstall”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall)

Comment: i have this error "Python3.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0"  on apline linux. What can i do ?

Comment: For me this error occurs within "pipenv shell"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/local/lib/` to the library search path. You can call the following in the current shell before running `python3.7`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

Or run `ldconfig` to add the path to the linker cache:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: it worked when I used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib` but do I need to use this command everytime before using python3.7?

Comment: when I used `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` it returned some output. I've posted it in the question above. I think it's a error saying it's not a symbolic link or something.

Comment: Nothing to worry about in that output.

Comment: So it it done now? I mean will it work always even after reboot?

Comment: Yes, it should work after rebooting if you made the changes permanent as explained above. If you only used `export` in the current shell it will only impact the current shell session.

Comment: I haven't make changes permanent. Can you please also include those steps in the answer above. I really don't know how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201679/discussion-between-john-and-user-12).

Comment: `sudo ldconfig` did it for me

Comment: None of these worked for me. No error messages or console output.

Comment: This fixes it for me for some time, but after a while it starts failing again.

Answer (score 20):

I just installed the required library using:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.7
```

Comment: gets libpython3.7 but does not seem to pick up libpython3.7m,  from deadsnakes and defaults.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using homebrew/linuxbrew to manage my latest python3 version. Doing this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3/lib` works for me (no reboot need).

Comment: Thanks, also came up with this - since docker-compose version 1.25.5 it was broken for me in a Ubuntu 18.04.4 environment using linuxbrew inside WSL with message: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/docker-compose/1.25.5_2/libexec/bin/python3.8: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install uwsgi` worked for me