# dlopen: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker-compose, archlinux

I use [EndeavourOS](https://endeavouros.com/) and have updated my system on February 17 2022 using

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Eversince, when I run `docker-compose`, I get this error message:

> [4221] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIgGJQGW/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Some forum threads suggested to reinstall docker-compose, which I did. I tried the following solution, but both without success:

[Python3.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649177/python3-7-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-7m-so-1-0)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that you use docker-compose instead of docker compose, which are two different binaries. docker-compose is also known as V1, and is deprecated since April 26, 2022. Since then, it does not receive updates or patches, other than high-severity security patches.

So, to fix your issue, use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`. If you compare `docker compose version` and `docker-compose version`, you will see that this uses the newer docker compose and runs without an issue.

Answer (score 63):

Install `libxcrypt-compat` from pacman (Official Repositories)

Answer (score 16):

Same thing happened to me today, this is what I did to fix it (Arcolinux 5.16.10-arch1-1)

Removed docker-compose

```
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Reinstalled it using pip (was not working with the curl method)

```
$ sudo pip install docker-compose
```

Comment: Note this installs old (v1) version of `docker-compose`, while the one being currently developed is v2. Also, manually removing binaries is definitely NOT a recommended way of removing software from any Linux-based system.

Comment: @MaksBabarowski: Thank you! I had V1 installed before, so it is suitable for the time being. Docker suggests in their docs to uninstall by remove binaries manually.

Answer (score 15):

I use Arch Linux and it worked for me:

```
 # cd /usr/lib
 # sudo ln ./libcrypt.so libcrypt.so.1
 # docker-compose -v

 docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Answer (score 2):

I found several forum posts explaining to isntall libxcrypt-compat from AUR. I did not like this solution, but apparently, this is the way for now: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274160&p=2

If there is a PGP key error when building the package from AUR, use this workaround as explained by Stock44 on this page: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libxcrypt-compat

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 678CE3FEE430311596DB8C16F52E98007594C21D
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>

Comment: It's in official repos as well. `pamac install libxcrypt-compat` did the job for me.