# Segfault on fresh compile of Python3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, gcc

I compiled Python3.8.2 from scratch on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Here's what I did:

```
tar xvzf Python3.8.2.tar.xz
cd Python3.8.2
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto
make -j8
sudo make altinstall
```

This is the same as I've done for other Python versions. When I open up a terminal, I get the following segfault anytime I want to assign memory:

```
herman@X1-Extreme ⏎  python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar  2 2020, 12:53:45) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test = ''
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm wondering if this is related to `--enable-optimizations` but I thought that runs the test suite as part of the process...

Comment: I followed your steps above (bar the `sudo make altinstall`) but don't get the problem when I run `./python` from the working dir ... could it be picking up wrong libs from somewhere despite the `altinstall`?

Comment: I ran `sudo make install` in the directory and it's good now

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018816/3420114) I just ran `sudo make install` and it's fixed now