# Anki will not start

Tags: python, module, sqlite, ubuntu-12.04, importerror

I have been trying to install Anki on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I try to start it from the application menu nothing happens.
I've tried to start it form the terminal and I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from aqt.qt import *
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 10, in <module>
from anki.utils import isWin, isMac
  File "/usr/share/anki/anki/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
from anki.storage import Collection
  File "/usr/share/anki/anki/storage.py", line 11, in <module>
from anki.db import DB
  File "/usr/share/anki/anki/db.py", line 11, in <module>
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I have looked around the forums for advice on installing sqlite3 and used

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

then rebuilt Python but the error still persists.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named \_sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3)