# ImportError: No module named pysqlite2 while installing Firefox sync server

Tags: python, python-2.7, firefox, virtualenv

I'm trying to install firefox syncserver as described here [Firefox Sync Server Installation](https://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html#howto-run-sync15). As such I did the following

1. Installed Python2.7 and Virtualenv
2. `git clone https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver`
3. `cd syncserver`
4. `sudo make build`

Everything was fine but when I ran `sudo make test` I get the following error [image]

When I check the virtualenv site I see this [image]

I'm not sure if this is related or what needs to be done here. Seems like virtualenv is using it's own local python setup not the system python. How do I make it use the system python. I tried tampering with the Makefile with no results.

Comment: Virtualenv is used to have own local setup for python. If you don't need it don't use it.

Comment: I mean I need virtualenv to use its own python. The issue seems to be happening because the python in virtualenv and the system python are different versions from what I can infer. I'm sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Did you try to install `pysqlite2` with `pip` ?

Comment: Don't use `sudo`. The install guide does not say to use sudo... For anybody wondering, like @furas: `make build` actually sets up a virtualenv and installs dependencies from a repo-provided [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver/blob/master/requirements.txt). Back to OP: python since 2.5 (via SQLAlchemy) shouldn't attempt to import `pysqlite2` in the first place, but import the built-in `sqlite3` module. This sounds to me that the python you're using was compiled [without sqlite3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3) support.