# How do I configure the sqlite3 module to work with Django 1.10?

Tags: linux, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, sqlite

So the issue is that apparently Django uses the sqlite3 that is included with python, I have sqlite3 on my computer and it works fine on its own. I have tried many things to fix this and have not found a solution yet.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue so that I can use Django on my computer.

`:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 6 2016, 14:10:16)
[GCC 6.2.0 20161005] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

`>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'`

`>>> exit()`

Comment: Try answers from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: I tried installing libsqlite3-dev, then I get an ImportError, "No module named 'ConfigParser' and then dpkg returns an error code (1)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that this error was caused by me changing my python path to 3.5 from the default of 2.7.