# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' python django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am running simple python `manage.py runserver` and getting this error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I had tried everything like installing sqlite3,sqlite-devel but nothing works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3 , check out this question

Comment: Already tried this

Answer (score -1):

Try to make a new virtual environment with `virtualenv`, `conda` or any other way you know and then activate your virtualenv, install any package you need inside that to avoid versions conflict problems. Now you can run the app.

Hope this works