# How do I run sqlite3 on Centos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, centos

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

If I run sqlite3 --version I get:

```
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

I'm using python3.6.0, does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: @Torxed it was me , I brought it back :)