# import nltk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite3'

Tags: python, nltk, embedded-linux, buildroot, superuser

I'm using buildroot to add python nltk package. When I try to `import nltk`, it gives the error as follows,

```
import nltk
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from nltk.translate import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/translate/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score as meteor
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/translate/meteor_score.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import WordNetCorpusReader, wordnet
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite3'
```

in the `core python3 modules`, I select `sqlite module`, and in `database`, I select `sqlite`, but it doesn't work.

Here are some cmd I tried

```
# python --version
Python 3.10.5

# python3 --version
Python 3.10.5

# find / -name sqlite*
/usr/bin/sqlite3

# pip list
Package       Version
------------- ---------
click         8.1.3
colorama      0.4.4
joblib        1.2.0
nltk          3.7
numpy         1.23.3
pip           21.2.4
regex         2022.9.13
SciPy         1.8.0
setuptools    63.2.0
threadpoolctl 3.1.0
tqdm          4.40.1
```

nltk-3.7 is extracted and installed from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/nltk/)

Can I get some help, pls?

Comment: Weird. Python version? How did you install nltk?

Comment: python version is 3.10.5, I downloaded and installed nltk from https://pypi.org/project/nltk/, and then `pip install`

Comment: Can you import sqlite3 in Python console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_sqlite3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993890/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sqlite3) or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170966/importerror-no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: no, when I try `import sqlite3`, it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite3'`, the answers from the link does not work for my question.

Comment: Well, since you cannot import it, sqlite3 module is not properly installed. Did you compile Python yourself? Either way, this question may need to be migrated to *superuser* and it has nothing to do with sqlite.

Comment: Did you do a full clean build after selecting `sqlite module` in the python3 options? If not, you need to do `make python3-reconfigure world` to explicitly rebuild python3 with the changed option.

Comment: @Arnout thanks, shall I `make python3-rebuild` ? does `make brt` work?

Comment: @PChemGuy thanks,  I compiled Python from source code

Comment: @kinderchen It has to be `make python3-reconfigure` to take into account the new configuration. I put `world` behind it to make sure the final rootfs is rebuilt as well - by default, `make python3-reconfigure` will *only* reconfigure and rebuild the python3 package, but not re-create the rootfs archive. I don't know what you mean with `make brt`, there is no "brt" package in Buildroot.

Comment: thanks, `reconfigure` works, when shall I use `rebuild` and when `reconfigure`? when I need to use `world` ? BTW, do you mind helping check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223700/numpy-distutils-system-info-notfounderror-no-blas-lapack-libraries-found), I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you did a build with `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3` enabled and `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3_SQLITE` disabled. Then you realized that the Sqlite support in Python was missing, so you went on and enabled `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3_SQLITE`, and you simply ran `make`. Due to how Buildroot works, this did not cause the `python3` package to be rebuilt, so you still have a `python3` without Sqlite support.

Two options:

1. Rebuild just `python3` by doing `make python3-dirclean all`
2. Rebuild the whole system by doing `make clean all`