# Trying to run a jupyter notebook on a Linux server

Tags: python

I am trying to run `jupyter notebook` on a server I have access to but it keeps throwing out this error:

I have tried using `pip3 install --user sqlite3` and `pip install --user pysqlite2` plus a bunch of other combinations which keeps leading me down a rabbit hole of errors.

Any help would be great.

```
-bash-4.2$ jupyter notebook
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/users/USER/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
        import sqlite3
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
        from _sqlite3 import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/users/USER/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
        from notebook.notebookapp import main
      File "/data/users/USER/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 86, in <module>
        from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
      File "/data/users/USER/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
        from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Output1:

```
-bash-4.2$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: SERVER_NAME
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID: 807cc73fa4ba404192edd7c64de3cf3f
           Boot ID: 279d14738e2548d2b0622b399a9dfd40
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Output2

```
-bash-4.2$ yum install sqlite-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repo rhel-7-server-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/entitlement/766154663321574841286633-key.pem
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

Comment: It might be some missing bindings. Install  sqlite-devel  (or libsqlite3-dev on some Debian-based systems)
This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: Looking at the first answer there I try `pip3 install --user libsqlite3-dev
Collecting libsqlite3-dev
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libsqlite3-dev (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libsqlite3-dev
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So seems like you have multiple Python installations.

Do the following steps:

1. Go to your home directory
2. Make a virtual environment using

`python3.6 -m venv env`

3. Activate the venv

`source env/bin/activate`

4. Install Jupyter

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`python -m pip install jupyter`

5. Run jupyter notebook

`jupyter notebook`

6. To  open the notebook make sure you put localhost:8888 into your putty tunnel configuration and then open localhost:8888 on your local web browser

Comment: I get this error: `-bash-4.2$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
[sudo] password for USER:
sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: what is your Linux distribution? use this command to find out " hostnamectl "

Comment: I added the output to the original post

Comment: Updated post with the output

Comment: run it as a superuser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196085/discussion-between-akshat-katiyar-and-user113156).

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took and spent on trying to solve my problem!!

Comment: Also make sure you add the localhost:8888 to the tunnels in PuTTY :)

Comment: Ok will do it 