# import nltk eror, No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: sqlite, nltk

I'm in ubuntu, python 3.7.6

here what i do:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite-devel
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo pip3 install pysqlite
python3 -m pip install --user -U pysqlite3
```

I try to import nltk library.

line (1): **import nltk**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from nltk.translate import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score as meteor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/meteor_score.py", line 10, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 32, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

can some one help me with this?

Thanks for your time !

**Edit (26.03.2020)**

sqlite3 -version:

```
3.32.0 2020-03-12 17:54:39 ea914bec81c49625072fc9d23faa048300f3a0421e069d303b7203edcdfb3743
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named \_sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3)

Comment: No it does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade my python too 3.6 and it works!