# Python 3.6.3 unable to import _sqlite3 to run a SQlite db with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm running my Fast API project with pipenv and I use Python 3.6.3 as the interpreter.
For production I use a postgres db which works fine.
Now I want to test my api with pytest and sqlite.

Therefore I changed the db connection setup:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///./test.db")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
db = SessionLocal()
```

I also tried the connection string from the official [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlite) from sqlalchemy:

> engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

when I run my test , I get the following error:

```
   engine = create_engine("sqlite:///./test.db")
../../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/test-hhG2yARU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py:298: in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
../../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/test-hhG2yARU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py:560: in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
../../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/test-hhG2yARU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py:473: in dbapi
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py:23: in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py:27: in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I have seen in the source code that the error causing module has the following note:

```
 pysqlite2/dbapi2.py: the DB-API 2.0 interface
#
# Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Gerhard Häring <gh@ghaering.de>
#
# This file is part of pysqlite.
```

Here the error is cause by

```
from _sqlite3 import *
```

where _sqlite is not found.
I had a look at the

> dbapi2.py
> file from pysqlite3. Here sqlite is imported without the "_".
> So I thought since python3 the pysqlite3 file should be inbuilt in python.

Is there a way to change the pysqlite2 to 3? I've read about installing pysqlite3, but this did not change anything in my case.

I also tried to update from python 3.6.13 to 3.6.3 as 3.6 is mandatory. This also did not change the behaviour.

Comment: If you have compiled python3 yourself, the sqlite3 development headers (and library) needs to be available. Depending which distribution you're using, it should be available under `libsqlite3-dev` or similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: I installed python with pyenv.

Comment: Does that mean I have to add them manally?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by the information provided by @MatsLindh
Here is the original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3#comment85352306_24449632) with the solution.
I have installed

> `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

and then reinstalled my python version with pyenv