# Why spyder and other tools do not work in Poetry env?

Tags: spyder, python-poetry, pyenv

I have this issue.
I have spyder running without any environment (version 5.2.x).  When I add it to poetry env (poetry add spyder --group dev), it doesn't work.  Next is the output:

```
  fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 256, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1823, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/utils.py", line 289, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 732, in setup
    internal_plugins = find_internal_plugins()
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/find_plugins.py", line 40, in find_internal_plugins
    mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name)
  File "/home/vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/plugins/editor/plugin.py", line 49, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.editor.widgets.codeeditor import CodeEditor
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/plugins/editor/widgets/codeeditor.py", line 33, in <module>
    from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "/home/vladimir/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/nptprediction-fB9y5jZ9-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/home/vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I really don't know what is happening.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210664

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: This is the output of what? What command?

Comment: The command is >poetry run spyder, after >poetry add spyder --group dev

Comment: You need to insert this very important detail into your question at the right place (not as an edit at the end of the question).

Comment: Why do you want to call Spyder from a poetry env, since you're already using it stand-alone? A better option in my eyes could be to go to Preferences -> Python interpreter -> Use the following... -> set the poetry env Python binary there. You might need to add `spyder-kernels` as a dependency to your pyproject.toml for this to work.